# Django - can I add a form on changelist_view?

Tags: django

I have a model admin with a simple custom change view page, can I add a form on it?

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    user_input_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'custom_template.html'
  
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_content=None):
        # How do I link the form to this view ?

        # logic of handling data from the form
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=None)
```